# passing json object with ajax to php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have set up a basic api and I know its working because requests that come with postman pass normally ,what I am having trouble with is passing the JSON object through AJAX to the php file.

The AJAX part

```
function add_book(){
    if(validate()){
        var jsonData = {};
        jsonData.Price = document.getElementsByName("Price")[0].value;
        jsonData.Title = document.getElementsByName("Title")[0].value;
        jsonData.Author = document.getElementsByName("Author")[0].value;
        jsonData.Genre = document.getElementsByName("select_dropdown")[0].value;
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "/books.php";
            request.open("POST", url, true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                }
            }
            request.send(jsonData);
        }
}
```

For example this is the alert I get from stringifying the object 
{"Price":"23","Title":"asdas","Author":"dasda","Genre":"Science fiction"}
I can basically copy/paste this string to postman and it works as intended.
Now to the php part

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
if(!empty($json_obj->Price) && !empty($json_obj->Genre) && !empty($json_obj->Author) && !empty($json_obj->Title)){
```

The if always returns false ,while it should not ,again postman requests pass for true.

========================================================================
EDIT : 
I managed to find the source of the problem . I made a function to check if the json is valid , turns out its not , there is no problem in the php part as it turns out . Here is the function in case someone needs it / wonders :

```
function isValidJSON($str) {
   json_decode($str);
   return json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

=========================================================================Edit 2:
The problem was on the `request.send(jsonData);` part . Fixed it with `request.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));`

Thanks for your time !

Comment: There is not enough code here to help, especially the PHP. Are you able to get the file contents?

Comment: What prints if you do `var_dump($json_obj);` before the `if` statement ? But with browser, not with postman.

Comment: Thanks for your answers , I managed to find the source of the problem . 
I made a function to check if the json is valid , turns out its not , there is no problem in the php part as it turns out

Comment: Then you should delete the question as the original has nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem 
    $json str = file_get_contents('php://input');

The post parameters should be accessed by `$_POST`.

Instead try this

```
$json_str = $_REQUEST['jsonData']`;
```

and also do a `var_dump` for `$json_str`

Comment: you stringuify to do the alert `alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));` , but you never do to send the data. 
´jsonData´ is still an object of javascript

Comment: Undefined index jsonData

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
    if(!empty($json_obj['Price']) && !empty($json_obj['Genre']) && !empty($json_obj['Author']) && !empty($json_obj['Title'])){
```

Comment: I swapped $json_obj with $json_str , and that didn't work either , but postman requests no longer pass for true

Comment: Trying with postman gives me this error
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ....

Trying with ajax still gives false

Comment: A good answer does not ask a question. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Will keep this in my mind while answering in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the file_get_contents(). Maybe you try to echo it.
And for the if you could write:

```
if (!(empty($json_obj->Price) && empty($json_obj->Genre) && empty($json_obj->Author) && empty($json_obj->Title)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Php echoes [object Object]  and the solution you provided isn't working,